# Webservice.deploy_from_image fails with "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'creation_state'"

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to deploy an image to a web service in an Azure Container Instance using the new ML service SDK. The `Webservice.deploy_from_image` method is failing with the following messages:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:/Users/chrcam/git/amlIrisClassification/deploy_iris_to_aci.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     workspace = ws)   File "C:\Users\chrcam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\webservice\webservice.py",
> line 258, in deploy_from_image
>     return deployment_config._webservice_type._deploy(workspace, name, image, deployment_config)   File
> "C:\Users\chrcam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\webservice\aci.py",
> line 121, in _deploy
>     deployment_config.validate_image(image)   File "C:\Users\chrcam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\webservice\webservice.py",
> line 883, in validate_image
>     if image.creation_state != 'Succeeded': AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'creation_state'
```

I started on the 1.68 release of the SDK and just upgraded to 1.80 with the same result.

The model and image are both registered in the my workspace.

The code is fairly simple. Any feedback or direction would be helpful.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice

ws = Workspace.from_config()

image_name = 'irisimage'
service_name = 'aciiris'

aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 1, 
                                               memory_gb = 1, 
                                               tags = {"data": "iris", "type": "classification"},
                                               description = 'Iris Classification')

service = Webservice.deploy_from_image(deployment_config = aciconfig,
                                            image = image_name,
                                            name = service_name,
                                            workspace = ws)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. Maybe this will help someone else. The deploy_from_image method requires an Image object, not the image name as a parameter. The error message was misleading and I was thinking there might be a bug in the SDK.

Here's the updated code:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Image
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice

ws = Workspace.from_config()

image_name = 'irisimage'
service_name = 'aciiris'

image = Image(name=image_name, workspace=ws)

aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 1, 
                                               memory_gb = 1, 
                                               tags = {"data": "iris", "type": "classification"},
                                               description = 'Iris Classification')

service = Webservice.deploy_from_image(deployment_config = aciconfig,
                                            image = image,
                                            name = service_name,
                                            workspace = ws)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have already found the error in your code. I just want to add some things.

The error message actually points directly to where your error is. It tries to get the `creation_state` attribute from the `image` object passed down from the `Webservice.deploy_from_image()` call. However, the error message states that it can not get the `creation_state` attribute from a `str` object, which tells you that you should not pass the `str` name of the image, but rather some other object.

However, I can agree that many of the functions n the SDK are hard to understand at first glance. I have had my own similar struggles, but I am beginning to really find my way in the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/?view=azure-ml-py) now. And if you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice(class)?view=azure-ml-py#deploy-from-image-workspace--name--image--deployment-config-none--deployment-target-none-) for the `Webservice.deploy_from_image()` function, you can see that an image object should be passed, and not a `str`.